# Calling a function on every row returned by a subquery

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I need to run the following query to extract the values of my raster records in a specific point.

```
select st_value((select rast from mytable),
    (select st_GeomFromText('POINT(30.424 -1.978)', 4326)))
```

But I encounter with the following error:

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   SQL state: 21000

It needs just one record for this function but I need to extract values of all of records.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a subquery returns multiple rows, you must either use it in a common table expression (CTE  / `WITH` query) and `FROM alias`, or use `FROM (SELECT ...) alias`. In this case, though, it looks like it's simpler than that:

```
select st_value(rast, st_GeomFromText('POINT(30.424 -1.978)', 4326))
FROM mytable;
```

Both subqueries appear to be unnecessary.

If you truly needed the subquery you'd write something syntactically like:

```
WITH sq(rast) AS ( SELECT rast FROM mytable )
SELECT st_value(rast, st_GeomFromText('POINT(30.424 -1.978)', 4326))
FROM sq;
```

or

```
SELECT st_value(rast, st_GeomFromText('POINT(30.424 -1.978)', 4326))
FROM (SELECT rast FROM mytable) sq(rast);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Select st_value(rast),
       st_GeomFromText('POINT(30.424 -1.978)', 4326)
from mytable
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function with multiple columns, you can do something like this

```
SELECT (info).column1, (info).column2, (info).column3
FROM   (select st_value(rast, st_GeomFromText('POINT(30.424 -1.978)', 4326)) AS info
        FROM mytable
       ) AS foo
```